# warning message ordinal logistic regression in R

Tags: r, warnings, ordinal

This is my data head(both):

```
 season  gender age   prog     grade 
    fall    woman  old  FRIST       B
    fall    woman  old  FRIST       A 
    spring  woman  old  FRIST       E 
    spring    man  old  NMATK       C 
    spring  woman  old  NFYSK       A 
    fall    woman  old  FRIST       E
```

I want to do logistic regression where grades are response variable. I want to make four of which are independent.

Here:

```
E/A+B+C+D=alpha_1+beta^x_1+beta^y_1+...

D+E/A+B+C=alpha_2+beta^x_2+beta^y_2+...

C+D+E/A+B=alpha_3+beta^x_3+beta^y_3+...

B+C+D+E/A=alpha_4+beta^x_4+beta^y_4+...
```

What i have done:

```
    library(MASS)
y <- factor(both$betyg)
mod.fit <- polr(y ~ prog + gender + age + season, data=both, Hess=TRUE)
summary(mod.fit)
```

Then I get this message :

Warning message:
In polr(y ~ prog + gender + age + season, data = both, Hess = TRUE) :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs

I know this is not an error just a warning. I Do not know how to interpret it or what to do differently to avoid this message?

Comment: [This link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it) should be useful.

Comment: You say that you want to do logistic regression where `grade` is the ordinal response, but in your model code you're using some otherwise unreferenced variable called `betyg`. If I'm not mistaken, that's Swedish for "grade". For consistency I recommend you choose one name.

Answer (score 1):

Since your outcome is ordered, you'll probably do better with ordinal, but may want to check the proportional odds assumption. The model you're describing is pretty much what `polr` does, though they're not independent as you say. UCLA has a good tutorial on this.

As for determining which model is best, when dealing with fundamentally different types of models like these, I'd recommend cross-validation. Prediction accuracy doesn't lie, and any pseudo-R^2 metrics will differ in interpretation across models.

Also, since this question concerns statistics more than R coding/implementation, I'd recommend CrossValidated (the stats StackExchange site).

Comment: it was really very helpful. Receive a warning message when I use my R code. As I unfortunately do not know how to interpret.